# JNI interface pointer confusion

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native-code

I keep seeing the `env` interface pointer used with and without dereferencing, for example

```
env->DoSomething(arguments)
```

vs.

```
(*env)->DoSomething(env, arguments)
```

Are they actually different things? Is one from an older JNI implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the difference between writing jni code in C and C++, from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface):

> Note that C++ JNI code is syntactically slightly cleaner than C JNI
>   code because like Java, C++ uses object method invocation semantics.
>   That means that in C, the env parameter is dereferenced using (*env)->
>   and env has to be explicitly passed to JNIEnv methods. In C++, the env
>   parameter is dereferenced using env-> and the env parameter is
>   implicitly passed as part of the object method invocation semantics.

Answer (score 3):

They're the same thing; just a little macro magic. The nicer (first) syntax is enabled in a C++ context.